# What is the difference between GetItems and GetExtendedItems in TFS SDK

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

I'm at my first tries with the TFS SDK (`Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client`) and when came time to retrieve objects, I got confused on why and when I should use `VersionControlServer.GetItems` vs `VersionControlServer.GetExtendedItems`. What are the differences? Performance? Features?

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have a tradeoff between performance and features.  You can imagine that `GetItems` is a simple query, whereas `GetExtendedItems` is a join on another table (or tables), and less efficient.

An `Item`, for example, contains information about an item at a particular version.  An `ExtendedItem` adds in information about *your* version of that file as it exists in the workspace that you've specified in the query.  If you have done a `Get` on that file then fields will be populated with the version that exists on your local disk and any pending changes that you've made on it.

`ExtendedItems` largely exist for the [Source Control Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/use-source-control-explorer-manage-files-under-version-control?view=vsts) view; it can display information about both the items on the server *and* their status in your local repository in a single query.  This reduces the number of round-trips that view makes, but the `ExtendedItem`s query *is* more expensive than a query for simple `Item`s.

If `GetItems` will give you the data that you need, you should prefer that.  If not, use `GetExtendedItems`.

Comment: Thank you! Strangely, in my case, GetItems gave me what I wanted and GetExtendedItems did not since the ExtendedItem object did not offer the DownloadFile method.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what additional features GetExtendedItems would provide?

Comment: @bkqc It's basically the information about your local workspace version; I've updated the answer.